# Recursive find and replace based on file size

Tags: bash, replace

I want to test, for each subdirectory (of many),

(1) Whether there are two files (not one) with a matching string in the filename, such as:

```
find . -iname "*older.jpg"
```

Let's say that command on the first subdir results in two results:

```
Folder.jpg
folder.jpg
```

I want to remove the smaller file.

(2) If there there are two files in the subdirectory, compare the sizes of each and delete the smaller file, like this:

```
if [ $(stat -c%s folder.jpg) -gt $(stat -c%s Folder.jpg) ]; then rm Folder.jpg; fi
```

(3) So, considering (1) and (2), this should do the task, IF you are in a given subdirectory, this does in fact work:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/sdx/specific_directory
find . -iname "*older.jpg" > ~/iname.txt  #send the filenames matching the string to the "iname.txt" file
if [ $(wc -w ~/iname.txt) -gt 1 ]; then # if there is more than one 'word' (file name) then do the next step
    if [ $(stat -c%s folder.jpg) -gt $(stat -c%s Folder.jpg) ]; then #compare sizes
    rm Folder.jpg #if first file is bigger, remove that one
    else rm folder.jpg #else remove the other one
    fi
fi
```

How do you modify the above so that it does all of those steps for each subdirectory? For example, something that uses:

```
find . -iname
```

or something similar.

Comment: if there are more than 2 files, do you delete all except the largest one?

Comment: Yes. I assume you could run the script several times in that case.

Comment: I suggest, find and print filename with sizes, sort by filesize remove the last line from the list and delete the rest.

Comment: I am looking for a script solution that does what is shown above, but recursively for hundreds of subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your condition

```
if [ $stat -c%s folder.jpg ] > [ $stat -c%s Folder.jpg ];
```

This pipes an empty string to the file `[`. What you want is

```
if [ $(stat -c%s folder.jpg) -gt $(stat -c%s Folder.jpg) ];
```

where `-gt` means "greater than".

Comment: Thanks - corrected that and revised question. One less issue.

Comment: @user3447273 You do not seem to have corrected it properly. Take a closer look.

Comment: You still have `[ $wc -w ~/iname.txt ] > 1;` which should be `[ $(wc -w ~/iname.txt) -gt 1 ];`